All non-Bash commands freeze the system after booting
Recently, my Raspberry Pi running Raspberry Pi OS seemed to have stopped working suddenly after having continouosly run fine for 2+ months (headless mode), as it didn't respond to SSH login requests anymore. When connecting it to a monitor and manually starting it, the boot process looked fine (no unusual systemd messages etc.).
After booting finished, I noticed this:
While all internal Bash commands work fine, such as echo, if conditions, while loops etc., any other commands do not return anymore. That means: When typing ls, touch, cat, nano, nslookup etc. and pressing Enter, nothing happens and the system does not return to the command prompt (only a flashing cursor is visible).
Occasionally, when booting, the login process also does not finish, i.e. after the Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by applicable law. line no command prompt appears.
In either case, the Raspberry does not freeze or crash entirely, however, since all keys I press are still displayed on the monitor. REISUB also works (but doesn't fix the issue).
I plugged the SSD (which I'm using instead of an SD card) into my laptop to see whether it's corrupted but I couldn't find any evidence of that, as all files could be read and written. Also, there's still 85 gigabytes of space left. What I find weird is that no log files are written anymore, especially not /var/log/boot.log and var/log/kern.log.
I tried plugging the SSD into different USB slots, which did not succeed.
What could be the cause of that? How could I possibly restore the system to a functioning state?


Note that I have tried booting and logging in countless times after 5 March.
Edit
pi@raspberrypi:~$ shopt -s failglob nullglob; printf '%s\n' *
certs
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
snap
Templates
Videos
pi@raspberrypi:~$ echo $PATH
/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v21.5.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ trap -p
pi@raspberrypi:~$ while IFS= read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done < /dev/kmsg
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ echo $LD_PRELOAD

_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ while IFS= read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done < /proc/self/mountinfo
[see output in screenshot]
pi@raspberrypi:~$ echo OK
OK
pi@raspberrypi:~$ (echo OK)
OK
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ /bin/bash --norc
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

[login once again does not finish]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ exec /bin/bash --norc
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ ls &
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~$ dir() (shopt -s failglob nullglob; printf '%s\n' *)
pi@raspberrypi:~$ dir &
certs
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
snap
Templates
Videos

[1]+ Done            dir
pi@raspberrypi:~$ while IFS= read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done < /proc/$!/stack
-bash: /proc/2854/stack: File or directory not found
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ls &
[1] 5808
pi@raspberrypi:~$ certs Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public snap Templates Videos

[1]+ Done         ls --color=auto
pi@raspberrypi:~$ while IFS= read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done < /proc/$!/stack
-bash: /proc/5808/stack: File or directory not found
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cd Downloads
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ls
AdGuardHome_linux_arm64.tar.gz nginx-1.25.3.tar.gz
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo su adguard
adguard@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Downloads $ exit
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ nslookup example.org
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.org
Address: 93.184.216.34
Name:   example.org
Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=21.4 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=16.5 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.485/18.687/21.404/2.040 ms
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ htop
[see screenshot]
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo reboot

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls() (shopt -s failglob nullglob; printf '%s\n' *)
-bash: Syntax error at unexpected symbol "("
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls() (shopt -s failglob nullglob; printf '%s\n' *)
-bash: Syntax error at unexpected symbol "("
_ [system hangs]
Alt+SysRq+R E I S U B


pi@raspberrypi:~$ dir() (shopt -s failglob nullglob; printf '%s\n' *)
_ [system hangs]



As you can see, the system worked for a short time perfectly fine (including NGINX, AdGuard Home, SSH, Uptime Kuma etc.), but not anymore after rebooting.
One thing I noticed in the systemd on-screen log (but never explicitly noticed before when the Raspberry Pi still worked) is that NetworkManager-wait-online.service failed to start (1min 10s / no limit). Not sure whether that's unusual.

while IFS= read -r l; do printf '%s\n' "$l"; done < /dev/kmsg would let you look at the kernel logs. You could try other logs as well.

You can redefine ls as ls() (shopt -s failglob nullglob; printf '%s\n' *) for it to only use builtins

Looking at /proc/self/mountinfo (with that while loop above) may also give a clue. Also /proc/<pid>/stack of those hung processes (like after ls &, look into /proc/$!/stack)

Strange that the system can still run bash. Does running commands with their full path works (as in /bin/ls instead of ls?) What's in $PATH. Anything in DEBUG traps (output of trap -p)? In $LD_PRELOAD? Is it the forking that fails or the execution of commands? Does (echo OK) work?

Can you run /bin/bash --norc? Or exec /bin/bash --norc?

Thanks! I tried out your suggestions and updated my question accordingly. Though I'm unsure how /proc/$!/stack could show anything, because ls & either hangs or I need to press Enter to end it. Also, why is (echo OK) different from echo OK?

Sounds like your system/SSD may have become corrupted somehow. Do you have a backup? If not, I'd consider starting from scratch; i.e. flash a new SD card. Once you get your system running, then make a backup (using image-backup. After you have a good backup image file, try restoring that file to your SSD using Etcher or the RPi Imager app.
